# Saved browser links prepend a period

Tags: php, html, apache, http

I maintain an old web app that was built with procedural php. (read spaghetti)

In order to trigger mobile style sheets etc, we pre-prended the url with an 'm'.

All of the sudden, saved bookmarks and home screen icon links are not working properly.

Inspection of the url appears proper. But...

Instead of loading

```
http://m.mysite.com
```

It loads

```
.m.mysite.com
```

And obviously fails.

Like I said, editing and inspecting the url looks proper, but no matter what I try, "http://" gets replaced with a period.

I tried inserting a little function in the first loaded file to check the first character. If it's a period, replace it with 'http://', but it doesn't even hit the page.
Clicking a mobile url shortcut in a desktop browser works fine.

I only have an iPhone6 to test with, but I'm being told that android devices are doing the same thing.

Enviroment:
Intovps 
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
PHP Version 5.3.3-7

Does any have any idea why this would all of the sudden change? I haven't touched this code in years and this is affecting all mobile users. If I create a new link in a note or email, it works fine. It only affects bookmarks saved in the browser, or shortcut links on the home screen, even newly created shortcuts. Bizarre.

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: See last edit above. It's been a really long time since I've looked at .htaccess on this site, but I don't remember it looking like that. I'm a total rookie with that file.

Comment: Has there been some change to the server recently that might have affected Apache?

Comment: The site is hosted at Intovps. I haven't made any changes, but they did a kernal upgrade several months ago. It was in June though, so I don't think that was it. They also did some "network maintenance". But that was a few months back as well. Nothing recent that I can tell. I just submitted a support ticket to see if they have any ideas or can tell me if they made any changes to apache.

Comment: Intovps support says they do not make any changes inside the vps. So they didn't touch apache. The fact that these links work from emails and notes etc makes me think that it's some kind of change to how shortcuts are handled on the mobile browser.